# APSX embedded sql query - date issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, date

I need to set a SQL query from a ASPX page that includes a variable date.year value.
I can't figure out how to get the year value into the sql query.

This works with a hard coded year value -

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dBconnString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dBconnString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [EntryData] WHERE [yearSubmitted]=2013">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This doesn't with a code year value -

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dBconnString %>"
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dBconnString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [EntryData] WHERE [yearSubmitted]="<%= Now().Year - 1.ToString>">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it at the database level, rather than the aspx level:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [EntryData] WHERE [yearSubmitted]=year(current_timestamp)"
```